# Poland work permit for EU citizen?

Tags: poland

I have a few different questions related to the Poland work permit. In case of EU citizen wants to move to Poland for work.

- If the company allows remote work? how much time can I stay outside of Poland and outside of the EU without make any problems with taxes? I don't care about permanent residency.
- Do I need to be always registered to an address if I planned to stay outside Poland for a few months?

Thanks,

Comment: Poland is a member of the EU since 2004. There is free movement, including for work, everywhere in the EU. So any EU citizen can move to Poland and work there at any time.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I assume you need to work months from the country because of taxes, for example in case of Netherlands, max is 6 months

Comment: @Ahmed that's a tax question, not a work permit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Poland is a EU country, you as an EU citizen have the right to move to Poland and / or to work in Poland. You become a Polish tax resident if you live in Poland or work in Poland for more than 183 days a year, but there is no requirement to stay that long. Tax rate is 12% for non-tax residents up to about 30,000 Euro a year and 32% for money above that; it is not clear to me how much you pay if you make say 10,000 Euro for two months.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.